# CSS! Horizontal resizable menu ul li, how to spread it on full width of the display?

Tags: html, css, menu, resizable

the site is resizable, so I can not use px, and sometimes it's a trouble with last items, they falling down when window go into small length, how to avoid this? let's see my single page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>li menu</title>
</head>

<body>
<style>
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3%;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
ul {
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li {
 background-color:yellow;
 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
 width:30%;
}
</style>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "they falling down when window go into small length" - what do you want to happen to them in this case?

Comment: that they stay on line and changing only their width

Comment: Yes, but when they reach some width, there wouldn't be enough space for them to resize anymore. What in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add white-space: nowrap; to your UL element http://jsfiddle.net/jvrCH/
But in this case menu elements will go off screen when not enough space.

Comment: thank you for the white-space, but it's only a half of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I you don't care about perfectly supporting old navigators, you could set a `min-width` on your containing `div` like :

```
div {
    /* current css */
    min-width:960px; /* which is the current minimum width for designing website for desktops */
}
```

And you could do the same on your buttons (and use `display:block` and `float:left` to keep `margin-top/bottom`, `padding-top/bottom` and `height` working):

```
ul li {
    /* current css */
    display:block; /* default display for list elements, could be omitted */
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    max-width:125px;
    min-width:50px;
}
```

And finally to correct the float issue (Parent element collapses if all children are in float) :

```
ul {
    /* current css */
    overflow:hidden
}
```

Instead of using the `overflow:hidden` trick, you could rely on the [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) solution